# Dynamic Legend sorting by values in Excel

Tags: excel, sorting, legend, diagram

My graphed data has about 80 legend entries and I'm only interested in displaying the ones with the highest values attached.

Is there a way to do this in Excel 2010? Manual sorting is not a question, as the graph is operating on a dynamic range.

EDIT: After trying [this](http://excelribbon.tips.net/T013214_Adjusting_the_Order_of_Items_in_a_Chart_Legend.html), along with all the included troubleshooting comments, I still can't find a way of a dynamic legend. Moreover I got dv'd for almost no reason (no comment + dv -> not much help)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Python and not Excel is somewhat of an answer. Still interested if this is possible in Excel at all, but it doesn't look like it from my research + community response or should I say lack thereof.